# Windows 2008 R2 - can't login to domain controller

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

I was in a process for preparing AD structure for SharePoint 2010 development. I installed Windows 2008 R2, downloaded all updates and run "dcpromo" after creating domain, I created few user accounts and then I created few more Managed Service Accounts via remote desktop as administrator and then I decided to logon as different user.

When I reconnected again, I got:
`"the security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"`. Same on administrator account or any other user (in domain admins group). I was trying to connect to remote desktop from my personal machine which is not part of the domain.

Unfortunately I'm getting the same error when I'm trying to logon on domain controller physically (locally) on administrator account or any other domain admin account. Also I can't logon locally at all (`<computer_name>\administrator` and others).

Also, if it might be any help - before I tried to switch users, I added "Domain Users" to be able to connect to remote desktop and also changed SPN for one of the users, but that was not the user I tried to logon to.

Any ideas why this might happened? I'd be very pleased if this issue could be resolved without need for setting up system again.

### Edit:

When I boot into DSRM, I can't connect with LDP.exe or any other tool. Active directory services are stopped, and when I try to enable them, message informs me that service started and stopped immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds very much to me like the computer account for the DC has been accidentally deleted. Do you think this is possible? If this is the only DC and you've not made many changes since this happened, you could boot into DSRM and log in using the restore password and try to restore the tombstoned objects, if there are any.

Comment: I don't think this is possible that account was deleted, but I'll check that.

Comment: When I boot into DSRM, I can't connect with LDP.exe or any other tool. Active directory services are stopped, and when I try to enable them, message informs me that service started and stopped immediately.

Comment: That's normal. In DSRM, the directory services are offline (if they were online it might cause problems with other domain controllers while you were making changes). You need to query the directory and make changes (if necessary) using ntdsutil. Also perhaps look at adrestore from sysinternals. Not sure if it can work on offline AD databases though.

Comment: I managed the problem by running DC in safe mode and used LDP from there. Everything started working when I removed SPN from one service account, which occurred to be wrong.